# Работа с изображениями в Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Подскажите, как лучше организовать хранение и выборку изображений в laravel?
И какие есть полезные модули для этого?
Изображения будут для авто и категорий. У авто будет галерея изображений.
У категорий будет только одно изображение.
Есть таблицы:
`categories: id, name, parent_id`
`cars: id, name, price, category_id`
Предполагаю что для таблицы `categories` нужно добавить поле `image_id`,
создать таблицу
`images: id, name`
а для авто создать либо отдельную таблицу `gallery`
`gallery: id, name`,
`images: id, name, gallery_id`,
`cars: id, name, price, category_id, gallery_id`
либо создать связывающую таблицу:
`car_image: id, car_id, image_id, type(основное, галерея)`
но нужно как-то помечать, какое изображение будет основным, а какое относится к галереи.
Подскажите, как лучше это сделать и с какими модулями лучше работать для работы с изображениями?
Подходит ли UploadImage?

Comment: spatie medialibrary там все уже ваше реализовано но по сути, да держать табличку image и иметь связь с моделью для данной таблицы м задавать индекс сортировки картинок и еще много нюансов которые вам нужны будт так что по сути это не будет просто id, name, path т.к. в будущем вам понадобится что-то типа resize, категории, несколько блоков картинок в одной  модели....

Comment: `либо создать связывающую таблицу:` так будет лучше остальных вар-тов. А насчет какое основное, какое нет - добавьте колонку tinyint is_main

Comment: Верно, не то что-то. В модель ещё можно добавить метод scopeMain чтоб в запросе брать главную картинку так `->main()`

Comment: удалил вопрос перед вашим ответом случайно

Comment: Если изображения будут для авто и категорий, то может стоит воспользоваться полиморфным отношением? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Comment: "какое изображение будет основным" - я для этой цели использую sort_order. получаю коллекцию, сортирую и беру первое изображение. Плюсы - можно дополнительно отсортировать остальные изображения в галерее.

Comment: @Yakoffka, а как использовать этот `sort_order` в коде?

Comment: Для получения отсортированной коллекции: $images = $category->images->sortBy('sort_order');

Comment: Для получения первого изображения: $image = $category->images->sortBy('sort_order')->first();

Comment: а в самом поле sort_order хранить integer на Ваше усмотрение. я обычно от 0 до 9 храню

Comment: @Yakoffka, @InDevX, подскажите, допустим нужно добавить новое изображение. Как прописать к этому изображению максимальное значение `sort_order`? нужно сначала сделать запрос и получить максимальное значение из уже имеющихся изображений?

Comment: @word ну очевидно, что да. Может даже придется снизить максимально возможное значение у других изображений, но в любом случае сначала надо их узнать.